# Changing color of all layers in geopackage at once in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, geopackage, color

For a project I am working in QGIS all the layers within a geopackage need to be the same color.

Is there a way I can change the color of all the layers to same color simultaneously or do I need to change the colors of all the layers one by one individually?

Answer (score 3):

Go to Project Properties - Styles, set Default Symbols. Set them and Untick "Assign random colors to symbols", readd the layers.

[image]

Or, set the style of one of each point/line/polygon layer, go to Layer Properties, Style-Save as default style - Datasource database. And all layers in the gpkg will use that style when added to the map.

[image]

Comment: If I send the geopackage to another QGIS user after doing this will the color settings still be saved to the geopackage?

Comment: If you save it as default in Datasource Database